# node.js: how to use sequence and promise to model two aync loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, sequence

I have two functions in node.js, let's call them func_A and func_B, they each needs to be called in a loop, but that needs to happen one after another..

first, func_a needs to be called num1 times in a loop.

```
for (i=0; i<num1; i++)
{
    func_a(i, function(err,cb1))
}
```

when the above completes, func_b needs to be called num2 times in a loop

```
for (j=0; j<num2; j++)
{
    func_b(j, function(err,cb2))
}
```

and when all of the above aync functions call completes and returns, I need to do something else with both cb results.  I can do the above using hellish callback pyramids, with counters to track callback completion.  But I want to use sequence and promise to simplify my code. How do I do that for the above?  I can't quite figure out how to accomplish it with functions called by a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making a promisified version of `func_a()` and `func_b()`, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the aggregated results in an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) without using a counter:

```
const promisify = fn => function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // forward context and arguments of call
    fn.call(this, ...arguments, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      } else {
        resolve(result)
      }
    })
  })
}

const func_a_promisified = promisify(func_a)
const func_b_promisified = promisify(func_b)

async function loop_a_b (num1, num2) {
  // await pauses execution until all asynchronous callbacks have been invoked
  const results_a = await Promise.all(
    Array.from(Array(num1).keys()).map(i => func_a_promisified(i))
  )

  const results_b = await Promise.all(
    Array.from(Array(num2).keys()).map(j => func_b_promisified(j))
  )

  return {
    a: results_a,
    b: results_b
  }
}

// usage
loop_a_b(3, 4).then(({ a, b }) => {
  // iff no errors encountered
  // a contains 3 results in order of i [0..2]
  // b contains 4 results in order of j [0..3]
}).catch(error => {
  // error is first encountered error in chronological order of callback results
})
```

To simplify the `Array.from(...).map(...)` mess, you could write a helper [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to invoke the asynchronous functions concurrently:

```
function * loop_fn_n (fn, n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    yield fn(n)
  }
}
```

Then change `loop_a_b` to:

```
async function loop_a_b (num1, num2) {
  // await pauses execution until all asynchronous callbacks have been invoked
  const results_a = await Promise.all(
    loop_fn_n(func_a_promisified, num1)
  )

  const results_b = await Promise.all(
    loop_fn_n(func_b_promisified, num2)
  )

  return {
    a: results_a,
    b: results_b
  }
}
```

---

As [@OleksiiTrekhleb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52597050/1541563) points out, the `promisify` function I've implemented here is also available in the Node.js core module [`util`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise and wrap your async function in it.
I didn't test it but the logic should work

```
let _func_a = (i) => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                func_a(i, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(res);
                    })
            })
    }   
    let _func_b = (j) => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                func_b(j, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(res);
                    })
            })
    }   
    (async function loop() {
        try {
            for (i=0; i<num1; i++){
                let a = await _func_a(i)
            }
            for (j=0; j<num2; j++){
                let b = await _func_b(j)
            }
        console.log("here you're sure both for loops are done")
        } catch(err) {
            console.error("some error has occurred")
        }
    })();
```

Comment: This doesn't allow the iterations of the loop to complete in parallel.

Comment: there is no parallel in javascript, but I get your point. If the author really need to run the for loops concurrently a solution could be not wrap `func_a` and `func_b` in Promises, but the whole for loop and then use the same logic, or `Promise.all`

Comment: `s/in parallel/concurrently`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [util.promisify(original)](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)?

The code you've mentioned might be transformed to something like:

```
// Dependencies.
const util = require('util');

// Promisify your functions.
const func_a_as_promise = util.promisify(func_a);
const func_b_as_promise = util.promisify(func_b);

// Now we may create 'async' function with 'await's.
async function doSomething() {
  // Some data containers if you need any (?).
  const someDataA = [];
  const someDataB = [];

  // First async loop that looks like sync one.
  for (i=0; i < num1; i++){
    someDataA[i] = await func_a_as_promise(i);
  }

  // Second async loop that looks as sync one.
  for (j=0; j < num2; j++) {
    someDataB[j] = await func_b_as_promise(j);
  }

  // Do something with someDataA and someDataB here...
  // You'll get here after all async loops above are finished.
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, if the code is not directly runnable in the browser, it shouldn't be in a stack snippet. I've converted it to a code block for you.

Comment: This has the same issue as [alfredopacino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52596280/1541563). Using `await` on each individual call does not allow the asynchronous functions within a loop to work concurrently, as requested in OP's question.